# Odoo 9 yes/no pop-up box python

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Odoo v9.

I would like to prompt the user with a yes/no option before certain python code is executed.

If this were in a button I could use the confirm="text?" attribute, however I do not want to trigger any database updates irrespective of the users answer to this particular prompt.

e.g. onchange event triggers yes/no box, which can then manipulate page, however the user still has to press "save" to keep any changes.

Is there any way of doing this using base odoo?

Answer (score 2):

`onchange` events can't return a dialog because they were simply not built to do that https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/what-should-onchange-methods-do-and-return-57760

You can use a wizard (it's not really a wizard it's just a form) and show it as a popup. our `wizard model` will be a `Transient` model, which would be discarded by odoo after a specified amount of time.

```
from openerp import fields, models, api

class test_model(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.model'
    name = fields.Char(string='Value')

    @api.multi
    def call_up_wizard(self):
      return {
            'name': 'Are you sure?',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'wizard',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'target': 'new',
             }

class wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'wizard'

    yes_no = fields.Char(default='Do you want to proceed?')

    @api.multi
    def yes(self):
        pass
       # sure continue!

    @api.multi
    def no(self):
        pass # don't do anything stupid
```

This is how your view would look like

```
<record id="cashadvance_list" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Test Dialog</field>
  <field name="model">test.model</field>
  <field name="type">form</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Test Dialog" version="8.0">
      <group>
        <button class="oe_highlight" name="call_up_wizard" string="confirm" type="object" />
      </group>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="wizard_form">
  <field name="name">wizard.form</field>
  <field name="model">wizard</field>
  <field name="type">form</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Confirm dialog">

      <field name="yes_no" readonly="1" />

        <footer>
          <button class="oe_highlight" name="yes" string="Yes" />
          <button class="oe_highlight" name="no" string="No" />
        </footer>

    </form>
  </field>
</record>


      <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_test">
            <field name="name">Cash advance list</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">test.model</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                  It's empty, create something
                </p>
                </field>
        </record>
```

In our `test_model` view we have a button that's shows the `wizard` as a popup, and then in the wizard buttons are handled by the `yes` and `no` methods respectively, this gives you better control over the buttons as you know have separate methods controlling the two buttons you have on the form.

I just put this answer, for anyone who happens to stumble on this thread and wants to know how to create a popup from a button.